# Java class import Error ! Liferay

Tags: java, import, liferay-6

I created a java class in a hook and I imported it in asset_publisher/view.jsp
like this:

```
<%@ page import="fr.liferay.hook.assetPublisher.TestAssetPublisherUtil"%>
```

and it gives this error :

```
 Only a type can be imported. fr.liferay.hook.assetPublisher.TestAssetPublisherUtil resolves to a package
```

I am using Liferay 6.2 ce ga2

Comment: You have to add class either in ext plugin or create jar with class file and put that jar inside tomcat/lib/ext.

Comment: how can I create a jar file ? thank you

Comment: @SoukaProgrammer, create new question for this

Comment: @SoukaProgrammer Simply export your package as jar from IDE

Comment: Ok, then how should I call for the jar ?

Comment: @Tony I no longer have the right ot post questions ! :\ to bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add class either in ext plugin or create jar with class file and put that jar inside tomcat/lib/ext.

As jsps in your hook will go to ROOT context, your hook class can't be referred there. You have to keep your class in global context(tomcat/lib/ext).